# Finding y prime, derivative trouble

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have $$y=\frac{4x}{x^{3/2}} - 8x - 2 \cos(\frac{\pi}{4}) $$

The best I could get it to was $$\frac{4}{2}x^{-3/4} - 6x - 2\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})  $$ but the answer doesn't even have a cos or even sin in it. I understood the example problem before this just fine, but it was a lot simpler and I'm completely lost on this...

Comment: What is the problem you are actually facing?

Comment: Basically it turns out I wasn't thinking oh the cos part is a constant and was making a small mistake when moving things around on the other end by doing something stupid..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, learn $\LaTeX$! 
$$y=\frac{4x}{x^{\frac32}}-8x-2\cos\frac{\pi}{4}
=4x^{-\frac12}-8x-2\cos\frac{\pi}{4}$$
$$y'=4\cdot-\frac12\cdot x^{-\frac32}-8\ \boxed{=-2x^{-\frac32}-8}$$
($2\cos\frac{\pi}{4}$ is a constant)